# Unable to locate package steamcmd

Tags: 16.04, server, steam

I'm trying to install steamcmd on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS server, but when running `sudo apt-get install steamcmd` it errors out with

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package steamcmd
```

I've already updated and upgraded. How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself.

First I needed to add `multiverse` to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main universe multiverse
```

afterwards I added the i386 architecture:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

now after an `apt-get update` I am able to install it.

```
sudo apt-get install steamcmd
```

Answer (score 8):

Run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse 
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1 steamcmd
```

Hope this will help. Or you can check source here:

- [How to Install Steamcmd on Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS | Xenial Xerus](https://freaksense.com/install-steamcmd-ubuntu-server/)

Comment: I'm not sure what people think is wrong with this post. It's not really the same method as [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/943940), though it should have the same effect. When running several commands with `sudo` already, enabling `multiverse` with `add-apt-repository` as shown here is handy, as is the link to a blog post with more details (unless some of the info there is wrong, but then I would've expected people to comment about it rather than just downvoting this and voting to delete it). If there's something wrong with this post that I haven't noticed, I hope someone comments.

Answer (score 1):

Dealing with this for awhile.   Used GUI to download the Steam Client.  Once I did that it installed a bunch of missing dependencies. Once I tried `sudo apt-get install steamcmd` again it worked flawlessly.